# Layout weight not working properly for nested linear layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I am tying to have an ativity like attached[image]

I want three rows, each row having three horizontal text views. Here's my proposed layout

```
<LinearLayout
vertical>
    <LinearLayout
    weight=0.3
    horizontal>

        <TextView
        weight=0.5
        width=match_parent
        width=match_parent
        />

        <TextView
        weigth=0.25
        width=match_parent
        width=match_parent
        />

        <TextView
        weigth=0.25
        width=match_parent
        width=match_parent
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <SIMILAR LINEAR LAYOUTS HERE>

</LinearLayout
```

With this, the TextView with 50% is getting stacked to the very left with no width at all. I am not sure what is going to wrong though. When i put all three views of same weight, they stack up nicely horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If you give `layout_weight` and `layout_width` at the same time(for horizontal orientations), it works like below

> sum of width = **layout_weight** + **layout_width**

`Vertical` Orientation also has the same logic.

Change your layout to this and try again:

```
<LinearLayout
vertical>
    <LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_weight=0.3
    horizontal>

        <TextView
        android:layout_weight=0.5
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

        <TextView
        android:layout_weight=0.25
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

        <TextView
        android:layout_weight=0.25
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <SIMILAR LINEAR LAYOUTS HERE>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:weightSum` of the parent is optional, because it is set to the children's layout_weight sum by default. Here is the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/bpblack"
        android:text="AAAAA"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

For secont and third block I specified weight = 0. They no longer claim space and occupy the width of the content, and first block takes everything.

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You gave weightSum as 0.3 and weight as 0.5, 0.25 and 0.25, but the sum of all weight should be equal to the weightSum so that it will fit the screen.

but in your code you first textview point is bigger than weightsum so first text itself will fill the screen,

As per your screen, you can give your weightsum as 4 and weight as 2,1,1 for the textviews,

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:padding="1dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0f0"
            android:padding="1dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:padding="1dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--your remaining layout here-->

</LinearLayout>
```

Gave padding and background just to show the difference in your screen.

If you want to fill the complete screen using the 3 linear layouts, then you can give the wightSum as 3 for the root view and can give weight as 1 for each layout like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:weightSum="3">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:padding="1dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0f0"
            android:padding="1dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:padding="1dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <!--your text views here-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">
        <!--your text views here-->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```